# Retrieving CRM 4 entities with custom fields in custom workflow activity C#

Tags: crm

I'm trying to retrieve all phone calls related to opportunity, which statecode isn't equal 1. Tried QueryByAttribute, QueryExpression and RetrieveMultipleRequest, but still has no solution.
Here some code i wrote.

```
        IContextService contextService = (IContextService)executionContext.GetService(typeof(IContextService));
        IWorkflowContext context = contextService.Context;
        ICrmService crmService = context.CreateCrmService(true);
        if (crmService != null)
        {
            QueryByAttribute query = new Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Query.QueryByAttribute();
            query.ColumnSet = new Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Query.AllColumns();
            query.EntityName = EntityName.phonecall.ToString();
            query.Attributes = new string[] { "regardingobjectid" };
            query.Values = new string[] { context.PrimaryEntityId.ToString() };
            RetrieveMultipleRequest retrieve = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
            retrieve.Query = query;
            retrieve.ReturnDynamicEntities = true;
            RetrieveMultipleResponse retrieved = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)crmService.Execute(retrieve);  
        }
        return ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed;
    }
```

And almost same for QueryExpression

```
QueryExpression phCallsQuery = new QueryExpression();
ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "activityid", "regardingobjectid" });
phCallsQuery.EntityName = EntityName.phonecall.ToString();
phCallsQuery.ColumnSet = cols;
phCallsQuery.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
phCallsQuery.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
phCallsQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("statuscode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "1");
phCallsQuery.Criteria.AddCondition("regardingobjectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, context.PrimaryEntityId.ToString();
```

I always get something like Soap exception or "Server was unable to proceed the request" when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

To get exception details try to use following code:

RetrieveMultipleResponse retrieved = null;

```
try
{ 
    retrieved = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)crmService.Execute(retrieve);
}
catch(SoapException se)
{
    throw new Exception(se.Detail.InnerXml);
}
```